# Guid.Parse failure with valid Guid - Encoding issue?

Tags: c#, .net

So, I have a valid GUID string below

```
Guid.Parse("e6f85ae0-f479-4e98-9287-98f7e62ba083") // Parses just fine
```

This parses to a GUID in .NET4.0 / 4.5

However this code

```
// Copy paste this line in VS Immediate window. Does not parse!!
Guid.Parse("e6f85ae0‐f479‐4e98‐9287‐98f7e62ba083")
```

Does not parse. The Guid strings are identical, or so I thought. Try it, in the immediate window of Visual Studio, the first does not parse, but second one does!

You can also verify with this code

```
var string1 = "e6f85ae0-f479-4e98-9287-98f7e62ba083";
var string2 = "e6f85ae0‐f479‐4e98‐9287‐98f7e62ba083";
bool isSame = string1.Equals(string2); // Equals false!! :/
```

Could this be an encoding issue? Is there any way to detect this issue and correctly parse the GUID?

Answer (score 2):

I'm half convinced this is a trolling question, but in case it is an honest problem:

Those strings **are not identical**. the second one uses the so called 'narrow hyphen' (`'\u2010'`), which is a completely different character than the regular hyphen (`'\u002D'`) and as such it is not parsed correctly.

Comment: It's not a trolling question, a genuine production bug. My question is - how to detect this and ensure you can parse a GUID which is human readable but not computer readable. This issue occurred because one system (outside of our control) re-encoded a GUID. As a workaround we have the rather hacky string.Replace('‐', '-')

Comment: @Dr.ABT You claim those strings are identical, yet you have a workaround that uses `String.Replace` :|. As for the answer - why do you care if those GUIDs are human readable? A bitmap containing that GUID would be human readable, but that doesn't mean it's a good way of transferring data. Which IMHO means that your workaround is fine - your upstream system returns incorrect data (which I doubt is encoding-related, but I dont' claim to know everything), so you apply the specific fix downstream.

Comment: They're visually identical to a human. Am I talking to a Human btw? ;)

Comment: @Dr.ABT Are you programming one?

Answer (score 1):

As decPL already said the the strings are not identical due to different hyphens used, So Guid.Parse will definitely fail. To detect that the GUID is computer readable you can use [Guid.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Method.

```
bool isValidGUID = Guid.TryParse(string2, null);
```

And there is nothing called human readable If you are going to replace 'narrow hyphen' then in case it contains some other symbol your code will fail.
Instead of using workaround I suggest you the debug the cause for getting the 'narrow hyphen'

GUID also supports various formats. If you want to validate a specified format then you can use [Guid.TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.tryparseexact%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Method.

Comment: yes unfortunately we have a third party system which takes our Guids and converts them to another format with the wrong type of Dash. We have worked around by doing a string.Replace of the hyphen character